# using setInterval to display time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the most current date and time that occurs every second but the output is staying the same. I dont want to use jquery because I am learning how to do this with javascript. The display function is being called by the body on onload.

```
function display()
{
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    var hour = today.getHours() > 12 ? today.getHours() - 12 : today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    var seconds = today.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = today.getMilliseconds();

    var output = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' - ' +
    hour + ':' + minute + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;

    setInterval(function() {

    document.write(output);

    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: No . With such way, the value of `output` is the same.

Comment: You put something in `output` then you write it to the page each 3 seconds. It won't know that it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
function display()
{
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    var hour = today.getHours() > 12 ? today.getHours() - 12 : today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    var seconds = today.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = today.getMilliseconds();

    var output = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' - ' +
    hour + ':' + minute + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;

    document.write(output);
}
setInterval(display, 3000);
```

*sidenote:* Is `document.write` is what you want ? You probably want to display it within a `<span>` or a `<div>` . In this case, `document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML` helps .

*another sidenote:* `setInterval(display, 3000);` and `setInterval('display();', 3000);` is different. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801700/188331) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the calculation inside the timer function, like this:

```
function display()
{
  setInterval(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    var hour = today.getHours() > 12 ? today.getHours() - 12 : today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    var seconds = today.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = today.getMilliseconds();

    var output = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' - ' +
    hour + ':' + minute + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;

    document.write(output);

  }, 3000);
}
display();
```

Comment: i tried that but what happens is that the loader keeps loading and nothing changes.

Comment: you will also need to call the display() function somewhere, to set up the timer. Just call display() at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

A value of a variable keeps static. So if you don't change the value of *outout*, it keeps the same.

So you need to calculate the date inside the interval callback and then display it.

Comment: i tried moving everything inside setinterval and in firebug this is what i see:  

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = output;

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'

function App(){
 const [exactTime, set] = React.useState()
 function p ( ) {
    set (() => {
      const date = new Date ()

      return (
        date.getSeconds()
       )
    });

  }
  setInterval(p, 1000)

  return (

    <div className="App">

      <p>
        Time is { exactTime }
      </p>

    </div>
  );

}
```