# Check if active PHP session when user returns to a page - JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have an app where a user absolutely must be logged in to use it.

I use PHP sessions upon login to store user data.

If a user leaves a window open and then returns e.g. an hour later, what's the best way to check if they are logged in still?

Options I can think of are:

```
1) check mouse movement which then fire AJAX php file to see if session still active

2) check as above on mouse click anywhere
```

But these will then be running constantly and therefore hitting and hitting the server potentially thousands of times a second with not so many users, so I doubt efficient.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a 'standard'?

I am using PHP and JQuery.

Comment: "logged in" and active are not the same thing. are you saying you have to know if they are 'active' ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascripts `setInterval(function, time)` function to poll the server every X number of minutes to check if the user is authenticated. Return a response in JSON based on said result.

See [javascript setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801543/javascript-setinterval) for a good discussion about the `setInterval()` function.

If you are in fact asking about a user being *active* on the website, you could use the `setTimeout()` function after X amount of minutes (such as an hour) to log the user out via AJAX request, or display a warning such as the ones in online internet banking.

If a user makes a request before the timeout occurs then this process is restarted naturally due to the request - response cycle.

Comment: Maybe couple that with a check that fires when the tab regains focus

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I agree.