# using function in setinterval javascript error using function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, timing

i wrote a simple function like a timer 
why does this code don't go right
is says Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined why?

```
function timeee(sec) {
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = sec;
    --sec;
    if (sec == -1) {
        clearInterval(cleartext);
    }
}
function timer() {
    var a = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var cl = setInterval("timeee(a)", 1000);
    window.cleartext = cl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801700/2801037), when you use `setInterval` with a string, the function is run on a global scope. However, your `a` variable is only locally set, so the `timeee()` function cannot see it.

Try using:

```
function timer() {
    var a = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var cl = setInterval(function() { timeee(a) }, 1000);
    window.cleartext = cl;
}
```

Or if you really want to use a string, define `a` as a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/2801037):

```
var a;
function timer() {
    a = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var cl = setInterval("timeee(a)", 1000);
    window.cleartext = cl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why?

Scope.

Consider:

```
function timer() {
    var a = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var cl = setInterval("timeee(a)", 1000);
    window.cleartext = cl;
}
```

*a* is locally scoped, but *timeee(a)* will be called from global scope. It doesn't have access to *a*. Try:

```
    var cl = setInterval(function(){timeee(a)}, 1000);
```

so you keep the value of *a* in a closure. Note that this will keep passing the same value of *a* every time, so you need to address that issue too (Banana's answer is one option).

Comment: Oh. Interesting. My guess was wrong then. This is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, my best guess to this would be that the reference to "a" is not a proper closure.

Think of it this way: you're passing a string to `setInterval`. Implicitly, when you pass a string to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, an [`eval()` somewhere is being called.](http://jslinterrors.com/implied-eval-is-evil-pass-a-function-instead-of-a-string). Because at runtime, the interpreter does not know that the variable `a` is being used elsewhere, it will throw it away. Then, when the `eval` gets executed, the argument `a` is not there anymore.

Now take a look at the solution to your issue:

```
function timer() {
    var a = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var cl = setInterval(function() { timeee(a) }, 1000);
    window.cleartext = cl;
}
```

Because the interpreter knows that `a` will still be used sometime later, it will not be destroyed. This is a proper closure.