# I have 3 images that do rotate but they don't go back to the 1st one and start over

Tags: jquery, css, image, image-rotation

I have 3 images that I want to rotate back and start over from the first image. 
Here ismy jQuery, HTML, and CSS. I'm believe the problem is with my jQuery code.

```css
#hero {
    width: 960px; 
    height: 300px;
}
#hero div {
    top: 324px; 
    left: 400px;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 0;
}
#hero div.previous {
    z-index: 1;
}
#hero div.current {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class= "container">
    <div id="hero">
        <div class="current"><img src="prayer2.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="prayer3.jpg" ></div>
        <div><img src="Prayer1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    setInterval("rotateImages()",3000);
});

function rotateImages() {
    var c1 = $('#hero div.current');
    var n1 = c1.next();

    if (n1.length == 0)
        n1 = $('#hero div: first');

    c1.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    n1.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current')
        .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000, function() {
            c1.removeClass('previous');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues with the code,

1. `$('#hero div: first');` - Unrecognized expression. It should be `$('#hero div:first');` - Notice the space.
2. Change the setInterval call to `setInterval(rotateImages,3000);`. The reason is `"rotateImages()"` runs in a global scope. **[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801700/3639582)**

Comment: hi I fixed that problem..But still it doesn't go back to the first image and start the slide show on and on

Comment: It rotates the 3 images once and then stops

Comment: oh no it actually works! About the spacing, you were right..That was the mistake I made..But I didn't remove the quotations so it works !