# How to make function work periodically

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
myFunction1(state, message){
    if(state) action1;
    if(message) action2;
    work every 0.5 sec
    if(err) throw e;
}

myFunction2(state, message){
    blah blah
    works every 0.3 sec
    if(err) throw e;
}
```

How to make function1 work every 0.5 sec and function2 work every 0.3 sec?

Is there just one way that use for loop?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html or are you asking about Javascript?

Comment: java or javascript? the two are **NOT** interchangeable - looks like javascript - if so,` setInterval` and/or `setTimeout` are your friends

Comment: [JS timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers), in particular [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript setInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801543/javascript-setinterval)

Comment: @AndrewL. that's sort of a bad analogy. "Cop" is short for "copper" and they both mean the same thing.

Comment: @naomik First time I've heard that before, always thought of cop as in the police, will change

Comment: @AndrewL. I think the saying originated as "Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet"

Comment: @naomik Believe so, though there's a treasure trove [here](http://javascriptisnotjava.io)

Comment: I think I like this one better tho: Java is to JavaScript as cancer is to Coca-Cola

Comment: @AndrewL. less of a treasure trove and more of a pile of internet garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval(function, timeInterval) if you want it to strictly follow the time. I mean if you want the function to be executed even if the function is still running.

Otherwise you can use setTimeout(function, timeInterval) and the call the same function at the end. But this does not strictly ensure the timeInterval since the execution time of the code before the setTimeout is not counted.
E.g.

```
test = function()
{
    //Your code
    setTimeout(test, 1000);
}
```